# Bootstrap and jumping to Anchors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a quick VPS main page for my dev server using bootstrap ( still learning ). But I cant get the anchors to line up to the top. I searched 2 hours about using bootstrap and different plugins to get the same effect as: 
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html

When you chose a menu item on the left the page automatically scrolles down. And the anchor is aligned to the top. I think this is done with jQuery but I can't figure out how. My links do jump to the anchors but just barely so that they are visible.

Can anyone tell me how this is achieved ?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're using a fixed nav bar, you need to add the same padding-top you have in body (to accomodate the nav bar) to the element you're anchoring too.

I found this article that explained it quite well here: [Fix bootstrap anchor tags position using fixed nav bars](https://web.archive.org/web/20180316075607/http://www.servermule.com.au/help/bootstrap-anchors-fixed-nav/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are using the [Affix plugin](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/js/affix.js).